# Why do pages not load in any browser after updating Ubuntu 12.04?

Tags: 12.04, updates, browser

First thought its a network problem but it isn't everything is fine.

My system is is fully updated, flash and java all up to date.

Just did a clean install of Ubuntu 12.04 every thing was fine, updated my system from the update manager, restarted it then after that.
Now pages like FACEBOOK(after log in),YAHOO,PICMONKEY,HOTMAIL etc don't load at all and comments section and certain other parts of pages like aas, omgubuntu.com, makeuseof.com, etc keep on loading but don't load.

Google search is loading as usual but results are not opening and pages keep loading.

Found a similar question here but didnt get any help

https://askubuntu.com/questions/161106/why-do-all-web-browsers-refuse-to-load-hotmail-after-an-update

Comment: Hi indronil, The question you referenced was closed because it was too localized, and the fear is that this one might follow the same path.  You might need to edit your question to avoid this,  What other browser are you using (I see you tried Chrome and Chromium).  Fore example you might want to explain what happens when loading a page using Firefox etc as Chrome/chromium could be the issue here

Comment: Are you running behind a proxy server? Do you have some spoofing software installed like, ie: tor?

Answer (score 0):

Try clearing your browser's cache & cookies

In Firefox/Chrome/Chromium:

> Ctrl + Shift + Delete

Comment: I have the same problem and strangely in Chome clicking CTRL-SHift_Delete makes the page chrome://settings/clearBowserData show up and continuously display the "loading" message like every other page with chrome..